# Request Instagram app to authenticate our website users

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

We have implemented Instagram Login in our site and it is working ok. The issue is that our users have the Instagram app installed in their phones and they are logged in there. But when they try to login into our website using Instagram Login the API opens a webpage asking them to login to Instagram and after that, they will be correctly logged into our app.

Is there a way we can ask the Instagram API to use the Instagram app to authenticate our users?